# javac and java command in terminal

Tags: java

I have a question below. I use JDK 17.

this is my codes.

```
package myPackage;
 
  public class myClass {
  
  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("test");
 }
  
}
```

1.When I write in IntelliJ terminal:

```
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass
```

Error:Could not find or load main class MyClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myPackage/myClass(wrong name: MyClass)

2.When I write in IntelliJ terminal:

```
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass.java
```

Program run succesfully without any error.

May somebody explain me why this happen?

Edit:
[This is directory and cmd commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8DqJ.png)

Comment: You've typed different commands -- `java MyClass`, which as the error message explains doesn't work because you left out the package, and `java MyClass.java` which uses the new ability of `java` to run a single class from the source file, without a compilation step.

Comment: so what is correct syntax without .java?

Comment: What's the first line of the `MyClass.java` file? Please [edit] your question to include the first few lines of the file _as text_ (not as image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `java MyClass`

This treats the argument as a *Fully Qualified Name* and looks that type up in the *classpath*. It does this by translating the FQN to a filename (replace all dots with slashes and stick `.class` at the end of it), so, `/MyClass.class`, and then looks for that file by appending that string to all entries on the classpath. This succeeds, in that `.` (the current directory) is likely on your classpath, and there is indeed `./MyClass.class` - that is a real file.

However, this then fails: This class file is opened, read, and java *only then* notices: Ah, this is a class file describing `myPackage.myClass`, and I wanted `MyClass`, so while I found the file, I'm not going to run it.

To make it work, you'd have to run `java myPackage.myClass` (note the lower case m here), which will look for /myPackage/MyClass.class relative to all classpaths. For it to work it needs to [A] find the file, **and** [B] that file needs to be the product of compiling a file containing `package myPackage; .... class myClass {}` in it.

> `java MyClass.java`

This is something completely different; javac treats this is as a special case (new functionality since Java 11), **solely** intended for very bare bones "I am learning java" / "Making a quick demo project". This bypasses all attempts to build a complete application and shortcuts the process: It opens that file, compiles it, and runs that class that was in it that was `public`, regardless of its actual name or package.

This 'mode' is triggered because the argument ends in `.java` *and* that file exists.

This does work and runs your code fine.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again as you advised.  But it didn't work. (package - myPackage, class in package - myClass)

Comment: "Did not work" isn't going to help. I shall counter with a similarly useless comment: "Well, it works for me". HINT: You need to be in `C:\foo\bar`, and un `java myPackage.myClass` from there, and then you need `C:\foo\bar\myPackage\myClass.class` to exist. Which you made by running `javac myClass.java` on a file with `package myPackage; class myClass {}` inside.

Comment: Thank for help, it couldn't work. I will add file directory and cmd in the post above. note: I removed package and commands work correctly.

Comment: You clearly do not understand the answer then; perhaps reread it? The right commands are, when in the dir that contains `myClass.java`: `javac myClass.java` `cd ..` `java myPackage.myClass`.